# Configuring CORS with Grails 3

Tags: rest, grails, spring-security, cors

I'm trying to enable CORS support in a Grails 3.1.12 app using this plugin: https://github.com/appcela/grails3-cors-interceptor

I followed the documentation and here is my security configuration in application.groovy:

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.controllerAnnotations.staticRules = [
[pattern: '/',               access: ['permitAll']],
[pattern: '/error',          access: ['permitAll']],
[pattern: '/index',          access: ['permitAll']],
[pattern: '/index.gsp',      access: ['permitAll']],
[pattern: '/shutdown',       access: ['permitAll']],
[pattern: '/assets/**',      access: ['permitAll']],
[pattern: '/**/js/**',       access: ['permitAll']],
[pattern: '/**/css/**',      access: ['permitAll']],
[pattern: '/**/images/**',   access: ['permitAll']],
[pattern: '/**/favicon.ico', access: ['permitAll']],
// EDIT: block all other URL access
[pattern: '/**', access: ['denyAll'], httpMethod: 'GET'],
[pattern: '/**', access: ['denyAll'], httpMethod: 'POST'],
[pattern: '/**', access: ['denyAll'], httpMethod: 'PUT'],
[pattern: '/**', access: ['denyAll'], httpMethod: 'DELETE']
]

grails.plugin.springsecurity.filterChain.chainMap = [
[pattern: '/assets/**',      filters: 'none'],
[pattern: '/**/js/**',       filters: 'none'],
[pattern: '/**/css/**',      filters: 'none'],
[pattern: '/**/images/**',   filters: 'none'],
[pattern: '/**/favicon.ico', filters: 'none'],
[pattern: '/api/login',      filters: 'securityCorsFilter,restAuthenticationFilter'],
// see http://alvarosanchez.github.io/grails-angularjs-springsecurity-workshop/
//  [pattern: '/**',             filters: 'JOINED_FILTERS'],
[
    pattern: '/api/**',
    filters: 'JOINED_FILTERS,-anonymousAuthenticationFilter,-exceptionTranslationFilter,-authenticationProcessingFilter,-securityContextPersistenceFilter,-rememberMeAuthenticationFilter'
]
]
// EDIT: Optimistic approach (restrict access by URL only) to allow 'OPTIONS' access for CORS
grails.plugin.springsecurity.rejectIfNoRule = false
grails.plugin.springsecurity.fii.rejectPublicInvocations = false
```

My problem is that when I send an OPTIONS request to any of my /api/something endpoints without providing authorization headers, I get a 401 status and I don't understand why.

Comment: It doesn't seem like you followed all the steps mentioned in https://github.com/appcela/grails3-cors-interceptor-spring-security-rest-sample-app

Comment: @ÁlvaroSánchez-Mariscal what do you mean? Which step did I miss? I didn't show it here but I also added some mappings to UrlMappings for the OPTIONS calls (which is said to be optional in Grails 3.1.4+ by the way, but when I didn't do it, I got a 404). With that, if I add the Authorization header with a valid token, I get a 200, but without a header I get a 401.

Comment: @ÁlvaroSánchez-Mariscal It seems like the CorsInterceptor is not correctly activated, even when I connect my Angular 2 frontend with the sample backend, so I created an issue for that in the repo: https://github.com/appcela/grails3-cors-interceptor-spring-security-rest-sample-app/issues/2

Answer (score 1):

OK, I noticed one key difference with the [sample project](https://github.com/appcela/grails3-cors-interceptor-spring-security-rest-sample-app). My project uses `RestfulController` and the `@Secured` annotation at the controller level, and that was what was responsible for the 401 on OPTIONS. I overrode all the methods to protect them at the method level and now I don't get a 401 anymore.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this solution (that worked for me, with grails 3.1.x):

CrosFilter.java:

```
import org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter;
import javax.annotation.Priority;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;

@Priority(Integer.MIN_VALUE)
public class CorsFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    public CorsFilter() { }

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp, FilterChain chain)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        String origin = req.getHeader("Origin");

        boolean options = "OPTIONS".equals(req.getMethod());
        if (options) {
            if (origin == null) return;
            resp.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "origin, authorization, accept, content-type, x-requested-with");
            resp.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, HEAD, POST, PUT, DELETE, TRACE, OPTIONS");
            resp.addHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");

        }

        resp.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", origin == null || origin.equals("null") ? "*" : origin);
        resp.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");

        if (!options) chain.doFilter(req, resp);
    }
}
```

if you use a plugin profile:
src/main/groovy/pluginname/PluginNameGrailsPlugin.groovy:

```
 Closure doWithSpring() {
        { ->
            corsFilter(CorsFilter)
         }
}
```

for web application profile:
grails-app/conf/spring/resources.groovy:

```
beans = {
corsFilter(CorsFilter)
}
```